# Splitting and saving data in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a data file and save the different variables into an array list.

The format of the data file looks a little like this like this

```
5003639MATH131410591
5003639CHEM434111644
5003639PSYC230110701
```

Working around the bad formatting of the data file, I added commas to the different sections to make a split work.  The new text file created looks something like this

```
5,003639,MATH,1314,10591
5,003639,CHEM,4341,11644
5,003639,PSYC,2301,10701
```

After creating said file, I tried to save the information into an array list. 
The following is the snippet of trying to do this.

```js
FileReader reader3 = new FileReader("example.txt");
BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(reader3);
while ((strLine = br3.readLine())!=null){
    String[] splitOut = strLine.split(", ");
    if (splitOut.length == 5)
        list.add(new Class(splitOut[0], splitOut[1], splitOut[2], splitOut[3], splitOut[4]));            
}
br3.close();
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

The following is the structure it is trying to save into

```js
public static class Class{
    public final String recordCode;
    public final String institutionCode;
    public final String subject;
    public final String courseNum;
    public final String sectionNum;

    public Class(String rc, String ic, String sub, String cn, String sn){
        recordCode = rc;
        institutionCode = ic;
        subject = sub;
        courseNum = cn;
        sectionNum = sn;
        }
    }
```

At the end I wanted to print out one of the variables to see that it's working but it gives me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I wanted to know if I'm maybe saving the info incorrectly, or am I perhaps trying to get it to print out incorrectly?

Comment: what is bothering or troubling you? it is not clear at all

Comment: You have a space in your split pattern, but no spaces in your data.  `String[] splitOut = strLine.split(", ");`

Comment: @RyanJ add that as an answer!

Comment: @Kick Buttowski The question is at the end, I'm getting an error when running the code and I'm not sure what is causing it.

Comment: @RELENTLESS00G can you be kind and post up the error message so we can help you better?

Comment: @RELENTLESS00G have you seen the Ryan J comment ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a space in your split delimiter specification, but no spaces in your data.

```
String[] splitOut = strLine.split(", ");  // <-- notice the space?
```

This will result in a `splitOut` array of only length 1, not 5 like you expect.
Since you only add to the list when  you see a length of 5, checking the list for the 0th element at the end will result in checking for the first element of an empty list, hence your exception.

Comment: @KickButtowski OP says he's getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I look at the code and that seems the most logical explanation for such an exception, given what's been posted.

Comment: Great, that worked! However, now I'm a bit confused on what is print out, it shows software2.GUI$Class@5b29c5d3 for list.get(0) and software2.GUI$Class@4df53935 for list.get(2), which I don't see at all in the file.

Comment: @RELENTLESS00G your list holds `Class` objects (not to be confused with `java.lang.Class`??), not variables. You need to address it in whatever manner you access individual fields within your `Class` object. `System.out.println(list.get(0).myField1);` or something similar

Comment: @RELENTLESS00G it seems you need to override your toString method

Comment: @RyanJ Okay thanks so much, I feel like an idiot now because it was such an easy answer.  On an unrelated note, do you know how to make a jframe file in netbeans be the main so that it opens automatically when you click run instead of having to right click and run that file?  I know there's two ways, typing something in the main file, or making it the main file, but I'm not sure how to do either one.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your data to have a comma or a space separating the characters then you would alter the split line to be:

```
String[] splitOut = strLine.split("[, ]");
```

The `split` takes a regular expression as an argument.

Rather than artificially adding commas I would look at `String.substring` in order to cut the line you have read into pieces. For example:

```
while ((strLine = br3.readLine())!=null) {
   if (strLine.length() != 20)
      throw new BadLineException("line length is not valid");
   list.add(new Class(strLine.substring(0,1), strLine.substring(1,7), strLine.substring(7,11), strLine.substring(11,15), strLine.substring(15,19)));
}
```

[ Untested: my numbers might be out because I a bit knacked, but you get the idea ]

Comment: Thanks, this is something the professor suggested at the beginning but I had no idea on how to do, so I made the deliminator.  This cut 40 lines out of my code and makes it look much nicer! 

If you care to know, the real numbers were 1,7,14,21,28,29,35,51,58,62,65,66,70,73,88,91,94,97,100 
so you were fairly close

Comment: You can at least vote my suggestion up, so I can have a few points for getting the same answer as your professor!!!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now.  I actually haven't ever been able to vote suggestions up because of required reputation, sorry.